# Фильтр dataGridView, фильтр чисел

Tags: c#, winforms, form, filter

Добрый день, сделал телефонный справочник, который берет данные из таблицы excel (по тз), нужно сделать фильтр:

1) Мой фильтр ищет только ПОЛНОЕ совпадение ввода в TextBox. Как сделать так, чтобы Фильтрация начиналась уже с первой буквы?

Я начинаю писать Р (пропадает все, что не начинается с р) У (уже останутся только одни руководители) и т.д.

2) И второй вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы он и по цифрам тоже фильтровал?
Заранее спасибо

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Excel_Load());
    DataSet da = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    private static string Excel_Load() //Берем файл excel из папки сборки
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        path = Path.Combine(path, "textfortest.xlsx");
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + @"; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRowsIMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0""";
        return ConnectionString;

    }

    private void DataView(DataSet da,string filtre ="")
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = da.Tables[0];


        DataTableCollection tables = da.Tables;
        DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);

        BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
        source1.DataSource = view1;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source1;
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filtre)==false)//Фильтр
          source1.Filter = "Подразделение = '" + filtre + "' OR ФИО = '" + filtre +"' OR Должность = '" + filtre+"'"; 


        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 55;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 200;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 55;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 70;
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 200;
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void DateBase(OleDbConnection conn, string s ="")
    {

         conn = new OleDbConnection(Excel_Load());
        string Strcmd = "select * from [List$A1:G350]";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Strcmd, conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            da.Clear();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(da);

            DataView(da,s);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();

        }

    }




    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pictureBox2_MouseClick(new object { }, new EventArgs { });

    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateBase(conn);

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateBase(conn,textBox1.Text);

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для фильтрации числовых полей их необходимо предварительно преобразовать в текст либо через `CAST`, либо через `CONVERT`.

Пример:

```
"CAST(MyIntField AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '" + filter + "%'"
```

Еще пример:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
        DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert([MyIntField], System.String) LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
    }
     catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLabel.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Фильтр должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
"Подразделение LIKE '" + filter + "%' OR ФИО LIKE '" + filter + "%' OR Должность LIKE '" + filter + "%'"
```

Вместо знака `=` нужно использовать слово `LIKE` и символ `%` или `*` в качестве подстановочного знака, означающего любое количество любых символов.

[Справка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) по выражениям фильтрации.

Ещё хотелось бы отметить, что в событии `TextChanged` не следует каждый раз запрашивать базу данных. Данные и так уже загружены в `DataSet`. В этом событии достаточно вызывать ваш метод `DataView`.

Да и вообще не стоит каждый раз создавать заново `DataView`, `BindingSource`, задавать привязку данных. Всё это должно быть сделано один раз при загрузке данных из БД. А в событии `TextChanged` нужно только задавать новый фильтр.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает как хотелось. Сейчас буду пробовать "Оптимизировать"
Может еще подскажете что можно сделать, чтобы фильтр и с цифрами работал?

Comment: @DmitryUshkevich - не понятно, что вы имеете в виду. Что значит "с цифрами"? Совершенно не важно, что вводить в TextBox: буквы, цифры, любые другие символы юникода. Фильтр будет работать со всеми.

Comment: мы не можем применить LIKE к типу int